# ZF2 Album tutorial using stored procedures

Tags: zend-framework, stored-procedures, zend-framework2

Please also suggest which namespace to use. I am new to zend and MVC.

**module.php**

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
// what code here?
}

**Album\Model\Album.php**

{
//what code here?
}

**Album\Model\AlbumTable.php**

{
//what code here?
//do we have to use this class or a different class?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the sudden confusion when starting out with ZF2. However, the manual has really done a good job at helping those who are just starting out. You can find the most up-to-date information here : http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/overview.html

Once you've got the Skeleton Application working I believe some of your confusion will be relieved. If not, come back and ask more specific questions OR you could even join the FreeNode IRC channel at #zftalk.

But to also help answer some of what you've asked here:

`getServiceConfig()` is where you will interact with the ServiceManager. Try to stay away from closures and work with Factories.

`Album.php` is sort of like the Hydrator. You don't have to use a Hydrator but for example purposes it was put here. It can make like easier in the long run.

`AlbumTable.php` is the Database Table you will be interacting with.

The namespace which is used in the tutorial is called `Album`. The Skeleton application comes packaged with a namespace called `Application` to start with.

You can manually download ZF2 here: https://packages.zendframework.com/

The latest skeleton application can be found here: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

You may also choose to use Composer to install your entire application which tends to make the installation process much easier for those just starting out, so in your situation I'm going to recommend you use that. You can find instructions on how to use Composer here: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html